# Finding the smartest student in students array objects using reduce function

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects (students) and I am trying to find the smartest student (student with highest score) using reduce function. This what I have tried but unable to get the correct result.

```js
const students = [{
    name: 'Chris',
    score: 75
  },
  {
    name: 'James',
    score: 54
  },
  {
    name: 'Alex',
    score: 32
  },
  {
    name: 'Mary',
    score: 43
  },
  {
    name: 'Robert',
    score: 87
  }
];

const initValue = {
  name: '',
  maxScore: 0
};

function smartStudentReducer(acc, student) {
  return {
    name: student.name,
    score: Math.max(acc.maxScore, student.score)
  }
}

const smartStudent = students.reduce(smartStudentReducer, initValue);
console.log(smartStudent);
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense, you always use the latest name but keep the higher score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reducer function should only set the `name:` property to `student.name` when `student.score` is higher than `acc.maxStore`. So you need to use conditionals.

Also, the accumulator needs to return an object with the same properties as `initValue`. I've changed `initValue` to be like the `students` objects, so I can simply return `student` when the score is better.

```js
const initValue = {
  name: '',
  score: 0
};

function smartStudentReducer(acc, student) {
  return student.score > acc.score ? student : acc;
}

const students = [{
    name: 'Chris',
    score: 75
  },
  {
    name: 'James',
    score: 54
  },
  {
    name: 'Alex',
    score: 32
  },
  {
    name: 'Mary',
    score: 43
  },
  {
    name: 'Robert',
    score: 87
  }
];

const smartStudent = students.reduce(smartStudentReducer, initValue);
console.log(smartStudent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually with every cycle of `reduce` you are overwriting the result. It doesn't really matter which one of the students have highest score, the result will be always the last student of the data array.

Secondly, you are missing some simple conditions to check if currently looped student has higher score than previous or not.

Suggested approach:

```js
const students = [{
    name: 'Chris',
    score: 75
  },
  {
    name: 'James',
    score: 54
  },
  {
    name: 'Alex',
    score: 32
  },
  {
    name: 'Mary',
    score: 43
  },
  {
    name: 'Robert',
    score: 87
  }
];

const initValue = {};

function smartStudentReducer(acc, student) {
  if (!acc.name) {
     acc = student;
  } else {
    if (acc.score < student.score) {
       acc = student;
    }
 }
  
  return acc;
}

const smartStudent = students.reduce(smartStudentReducer, initValue);
console.log(smartStudent);
```